# Apache Spark circular reference Exception when creating Encoders

Tags: apache-spark, avro

I am trying to generate a test AVRO file from a collection of objects represented by generated classes (TestAggregate.java, TestTuple.java). I used avro-tools-1.10.2.jar to generate those classes from this AVRO schema (dataset.avsc):

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "TestAggregate",
  "namespace" : "com....",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "uuid",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "bag",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : {
        "type" : "record",
        "name" : "TestTuple",
        "fields" : [ {
          "name" : "s",
          "type" : "int"
        }, {
          "name" : "n",
          "type" : "int"
        }, {
          "name" : "c",
          "type" : "int"
        }, {
          "name" : "f",
          "type" : "int"
        } ]
      }
    },
    "aliases" : [ "bag" ]
  } ]
}
```

When I try to create an Encoder using
`Encoder<TestAggregate> datasetEncoder = Encoders.bean(TestAggregate.class);` , it throws an Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot have circular references in bean class, but got the circular reference of class class org.apache.avro.Schema...
```

There is no circular reference in those generated files (or schema) as far as I can tell.
I am using Spark release 3.2.1.
Any ideas on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need an encoder (or the compiled class)

Take the AVSC text itself, and you can get a `Schema` like so

```
SchemaConverters.toSqlType(new Schema.Parser().parse(avroSchema))
```

Then this can be given to the spark-sql `from_avro` function.